# Chini's equation or Bernoulli equation? How to use quadrature?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadrature

> $y' - c y^{1/2} = f(x) $ $\quad \quad $ for c : constant and $f$ continuous

I am trying to solve the above equation that is presented to me as a Bernoulli equation. However, during my searches, I found that it is Chini-type equation.
I tried to solve it by defining a new variable, but anything that I defined, returned me to the initial equation. what should I do? How can I solve it? Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to consider $x$ as dependent variable and $y$ as independent variable? In this case we may get the next form of equation: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = g(y,x)$.

Comment: Hello. $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: I understand, but in order to solve this equation it's useful to work with $y$ as independent variable. It's a method of solution.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if I understand the method correctly. The function $f(x)$ is not given. So, how should I proceed?

Comment: this method may give an equation of the form $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = g(y,x)$, where $g(y,x)$ depends on $f$. Is such a form of equation suitable for you?